# Optimal substructure of shortest path and Dijkstra

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have very well understood Optimal substructure property of shortest path. Which says that-

> A shortest path from x to y via z contains a shortest path from x to
> z.

Now I want to understand how Dijkstra's algorithm is exploiting this property. All Dijkstra does is- Find minimum at current time and finalise that vertex's shortest distance.

How Dijkstra's algorithm is making use of Optimal substructure property of shortest path?.

I have referred many sources and nowhere found any connecting relation in these two.

Comment: The solutions that Dijkstra's algorithm finds conform to the optimal substructure property, but Dijkstra doesn't directly use that property to find solutions. Dijkstra uses two distinct, but closely related concepts: **visit** and **explore**. A node is **visited** any time an incoming edge to that node is used to reach that node. A node is **explored** when its outgoing edges are used to visit other nodes. The method that Dijkstra uses is this: given the set of all nodes that have been visited but not yet explored, explore the node that has the shortest distance from the start.

Comment: The key property of Dijkstra is that each node will only be **explored** once. A node may be **visited** after it has been **explored**, but that visit will necessarily have a longer distance from the start than the distance the node had when it was explored. So once a node has been **explored**, it never needs to be explored again.

Comment: @user3386109 you have explained Dijkstra thanks but I know how it works. My question is still unanswered :)

Comment: Indeed, but I did hide my opinion on the matter in that description: *"Dijkstra's doesn't directly use that property ..."*. Which is to say that IMO the algorithm wasn't designed based on that property. Which explains why you can't find any references that start with that property as the basis for the algorithm. The only person that really knows the answer to your question is Dijkstra, and you're a little bit late to ask him.

Comment: I am not yet convinced. My thinking is - "whenever we are including a vertex as final vertex in tree using Dijkstra then we are making sure that optimal substructure property holds". Suppose we include any other vertex then we cant satisfy optimal substructure property ?

Comment: On the contrary, you *can* select another vertex that satisfies the  optimal substructure property, but doesn't satisfy the requirements of Dijkstra's algorithm. So satisfying the optimal substructure property is a side-effect of how Dijkstra selects vertices. It is not a criteria for selecting vertices.

Comment: If we select another vertex then we cant satisfy greedy choice property. Algorithm correctness is also needed.

Comment: Good, so we finally agree. The algorithm makes choices based on its design. It doesn't make choices based on the properties of the output.

Comment: Yes it makes choice based on design but my argument is that both design and properties are inlined. And I want to verify if my argument is correct or wrong. 
Some proof that can make my claim false?

Comment: *"but my argument is that both design and properties are inlined."* Fair enough, the world awaits your proof. I've given you all the information that I have on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm uses the optimal substructure property in the sense that it considers only the optimal subpaths from the source node.

An example: Suppose we're trying to find the shortest path from `a` to `z`. Also suppose that we can only reach `z` by going through `y`.

Without the optimal substructure property, it would be necessary to examine all subpaths from `a` to `y` in order to find the shortest path from `a` to `z`, not just the shortest path from `a` to `y`.